# Get specific NSMutableArray values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray that looks exactly like this:

```
(
    {
        nodeChildArray = (
            {
                nodeContent = 11111122;
                nodeName = MyId;
            },
            {
                nodeName = ShowTask;
            },
            {
                nodeContent = 11115295;
                nodeName = MyNumber;
            },
            {
                nodeContent = 000003;
                nodeName = CatId;
            },
        );
        nodeName = Request;
    },
    {
        nodeChildArray = (
            {
                nodeContent = 22222233;
                nodeName = MyId;
            },
            {
                nodeName = ShowTask;
            },
            {
                nodeContent = 11115295;
                nodeName = MyNumber;
            },
            {
                nodeContent = 000003;
                nodeName = CatId;
            },
    );
        nodeName = Request;
    }
)
```

How can I create array or mutableArray that contains values of MyId? For example, an array that has (11111122, 22222233). How to get this values of nodeContent matching its nodeName?
It's like I want to get a nodeContent of a specific nodeName.

Comment: `NSMutableArray`s don't have key->value pairs. Are you sure you're using the `NSMutableArray` datatype and not an `NSDictionary` or something of the like?

Comment: yes, I'm sure it's NSMutableArray :(
how to achieve that? do you have an idea?

Comment: An NSMutableArray is NOT a sparse array.  To have an element with an index of 22222233, your array would need to contain 22222233 elements.  You don't want that.  You want an NSMutableDictionary.  Or you want to store your nodeContent and nodeName data in an array and use an NSDictionary as an index into the elements of the array.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but can you show me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the data you posted, I see an outer array of dictionaries. Each of those dictionaries contains it's own array of dictionaries. The inner dictionary contains your actual data, with keys NodeContent and NodeName.

I'm guessing you want to traverse all the innermost dictionaries, looking for entires with a nodeName value of "MyID", and collect an array of the NodeContent values for those dictionaries.

To diagram your data structure, this is what I see:

```
Array
  Dictionary
    array
       Dictionary
```

So the code might look like this:

```
NSMutableArray *nodeContents = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSDictionary *outerDict in outerArray)
{
  NSArray *nodeChildArray = outerDict[@"nodeChildArray];
  for (NSDictionary innerDict in nodeChildArray)
  {
    if ([innerDict[@"nodeName"] isEqualToString "MyID"])
    {
      NSString *thisNodeContent = innerDict[@"nodeContent"];
      if (thisNodeContent != nil)
      [nodeContents addObject: thisNodeContent];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your NSMutableArray looks like from what you've posted above, but I'll assume it contains objects that look something like this:

```
@interface MyObject
{
    NSInteger nodeContent;
    NSString *nodeName;
}
```

You want to loop through all the elements of your array and create an NSDictionary key/value pair from each element:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// myArray is the NSMutableArray you got from (wherever)
for (MyObject obj in myArray)
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", obj.nodeContent];
    [myDictionary setObject:obj forKey:key];
}
```

Now you have an NSMutableDictionary that contains the following keys:

```
11111122
22222233
```

Each key has an object associated with it.  That object is the same object that was in your original array.  You can then retrieve the object with:

```
MyObject *myObj = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"11111122"];
```

Comment: I get that NSMutableArray from a class generated by Wsdl2Code, and in that NSMutableArray as you see I have a field MyId. I need those MyId-s stored in some array and then show them in TableViewController.
But I don't know how to get these, because as you see all fields have that nodeName and nodeContent.

Comment: Then loop through the array and create a NSDictionary key/value pair for each element.  The key would be nodeContent (converted to an NSString).  The value would be whatever kind of data structure you need to build to contain the information for that element.

Comment: Can you help me? :S sorry and thank you for your time. At least some code example?  thanks again

Comment: Edited to add some more example code

Comment: I don't understand MyObject part? :( and obj.nodeContent, I get some errors :(

Comment: The example wasn't meant as a complete solution to be compiled and run.  I'm not writing your code for you, I'm just trying to show you how to use an NSDictionary to get your data into a format you can use.  I can't give you a more complete answer without more information from you.  What do you need to accomplish?  What have you tried?  What didn't work?  Show us some code that you have tried and maybe we can help you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
NSMutableArray *contentsForMyId = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in YOURARRAY) {
    for (NSDictionary *element in (NSArray*)dict[@"nodeChildArray"]) {
        if ([element[@"nodeName"] isEqualToString:@"MyId"]) {
            [contentsForMyId addObject:element[@"nodeContent"]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to do this, but I get an error that says:
property 'append' not found on object of type "NSMutableArray *" :(

Comment: it's like I want to get a nodeContent of a specific nodeName.

Comment: This is Objective C, not Swift :)  The append line should be `[contentsForMyId addObject: element[@"nodeContent"]]`

Comment: LOL thanks for the correction.  It's been tough switching back and forth!